# Flexslider no showing last item fully

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I use flexslider. I have a slideshow that show 4 items at a time. Every slide but the last is displayed correctly.
The last slide does not go all the way. What I mean is that until I reach the last slide I can see all 4 items, but when I reach the last item, I only see some of it.

My slider container is `900px` wide.

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    itemWidth: 225,
    controlNav: false,
    move: 1,
    slideshowSpeed: 4000,
    pauseOnHover: true
});​
```

Comment: Would you be able to you post the relevant html the `flexslider` class belongs to?

Comment: Try adding slider container to more than 1000px, itemwidth 225 * 4 =1000. just a suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with FlexSlider 2.1 ([GitHub Issue](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/286)). [Downgrade to 2.0](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/downloads) to resolve until a fix is released.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue because I had margins on the slides, and I did not set itemMargin appropriately so that it goes into the calculations for the slider. When I set the itemMargin to 5px (the margin I had in CSS) the last frame showed up entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/286